# How to collect maximal non-overlapping ascending/descending prefixes of a random sequence of numbers

Tags: sorting, prolog, mergesort, tail-recursion

Let S = [x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>] be a random sequence of distinct numbers. We can define a **run** of S as:

- a sequence **[x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>i</sub>]**, for 1 ≤ i ≤ n, such that x<sub>1</sub> < x<sub>2</sub> < ... < x<sub>i</sub>, and i = n or x<sub>i</sub> > x<sub>i+1</sub>; or
- a sequence **[x<sub>i</sub>, x<sub>i-1</sub>, ..., x<sub>1</sub>]**, for 1 ≤ i ≤ n, such that x<sub>1</sub> > x<sub>2</sub> > ... > x<sub>i</sub>, and i = n or x<sub>i</sub> < x<sub>i+1</sub>.

The predicate `runs/2` collects all runs of a given sequence of distinct numbers (for successive non-overlapping ascending or descending prefixes).

```
% runs(+Sequence, -Runs)

runs([], []).
runs([X|Xs], [Run|Runs]) :-
    run(Xs, X, Run, Rest),
    runs(Rest, Runs).

run([], X, [X], []).
run([X1|Xs], X0, Run, Rest) :-
    compare(Order, X0, X1),
    run_case(Order, X0, X1, Xs, Run, Rest).

run_case(<, X0, X1, Xs, [X0|Run], Rest) :-
    ascending(Xs, X1, Run, Rest).

run_case(>, X0, X1, Xs, Run, Rest) :-
    descending(Xs, X1, [X0], Run, Rest).

% for an ascending prefix, the run is built up as a QUEUE

ascending([], X0, [X0], []).
ascending([X1|Xs], X0, [X0|Run0], Rest) :-
    (   X0 @> X1
    ->  Run0 = [],
        Rest = [X1|Xs]
    ;   ascending(Xs, X1, Run0, Rest) ).

% for a descending prefix, the run is built up as a STACK

descending([], X0, Run, [X0|Run], []).
descending([X1|Xs], X0, Run0, Run, Rest) :-
    (   X0 @< X1
    ->  Run = [X0|Run0],
        Rest = [X1|Xs]
    ;   descending(Xs, X1, [X0|Run0], Run, Rest) ).
```

Example:

```
?- runs([1, 2, 9, 8, 5, 3, 7, 6, 4, 0], R).
R = [[1, 2, 9], [3, 5, 8], [0, 4, 6, 7]].
```

**PROBLEM**: How to extend this code to deal with sequences containing **repeating** numbers:

- modifying only the predicates `run/3` and `run_case/6` (in the latter, the arity can be changed);
- without explicitly using the predicate `reverse/2`;
- without processing the same item more than once;
- using only tail-recursive predicates; and
- the predicate `runs/2` must take time O(n).

After the modifications, the predicate `run/2` should work as follows:

```
?- runs([5, 5, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 7, 6, 6, 1, 7, 8, 8, 9], Runs).
Runs = [[2, 2, 3, 5, 5], [4, 4, 7], [1, 6, 6], [7, 8, 8, 9]].
```

**MOTIVATION**: The predicate `runs/2` helps to implement a (bottom-up) version of **natural merge sort** that takes time O(n) to sort sequences that are already sorted (ascending or descending), as well as greatly reducing the execution time to sort sequences that are already "almost ordered".

Comment: Sounds impossible, given those restrictions. Need more flexibility to change the predicates.

Comment: @brebs In fact, I think it's possible... perhaps trying to build up the run as a DEQUE (difference-list), before deciding whether it will be a STACK or a QUEUE... anyway, answers that attempt to satisfy some of those restrictions (if not all of them) are most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this (ascending and descending remain the same):

```
runs([], []).
runs([X|Xs], [Run|Runs]) :-
    run(Xs, X, [X|Tail]-Tail, Run, Rest),
    runs(Rest, Runs).
    
run([], _, Run-[], Run, []).
run([X1|Xs], X0, LInit-Tail, Run, Rest):-
    compare(Order, X0, X1),
    run_case(Order, X1, LInit-Tail, Xs, Run, Rest).

run_case(=, X1, LInit-[X1|Tail], Xs, Run, Rest) :-
    run(Xs, X1, LInit-Tail, Run, Rest).

run_case(<, X1, LInit-Run, Xs, LInit, Rest) :-
    ascending(Xs, X1, Run, Rest).
    
run_case(>, X1, LInit-[], Xs, Run, Rest) :-
    descending(Xs, X1, LInit, Run, Rest).

% for an ascending prefix, the run is built up as a QUEUE

ascending([], X0, [X0], []).
ascending([X1|Xs], X0, [X0|Run0], Rest) :-
    (   X0 @> X1
    ->  Run0 = [],
        Rest = [X1|Xs]
    ;   ascending(Xs, X1, Run0, Rest) ).


% for a descending prefix, the run is built up as a STACK

descending([], X0, Run, [X0|Run], []).
descending([X1|Xs], X0, Run0, Run, Rest) :-
    (   X0 @< X1
    ->  Run = [X0|Run0],
        Rest = [X1|Xs]
    ;   descending(Xs, X1, [X0|Run0], Run, Rest) ).
```

Sample runs:

```
?- runs([1, 2, 9, 8, 5, 3, 7, 6, 4, 0], R).
R = [[1, 2, 9], [3, 5, 8], [0, 4, 6, 7]].

?- runs([5, 5, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 7, 6, 6, 1, 7, 8, 8, 9], Runs).
Runs = [[2, 2, 3, 5, 5], [4, 4, 7], [1, 6, 6], [7, 8, 8, 9]].
```

Comment: Nice! As I've expected, difference-lists really help to solve the problem!